# How to kill Interface Builder process within XCode4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I read that this could improve the performance of XCode 4 which is running like a turtle. Is this true? And if so, how do I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Terminal, find the process and then kill.